# Postgresql can't connect application server through PGAdmin4

Tags: windows, pgadmin

I installed PostgreSql on my Windows machine.
I can connect to PostgreSql through cmd.
But when I want to launch pgAdmin I am getting this error message.

> Failed to connect to the pgAdmin application server. Click here to try again.

I have also Mysql installed on my machine if it can make any complications.

Comment: How exactly are you accessing/starting pgAdmin?

Comment: pg_ctl start -D D:\Postgresql\data

Comment: That starts the **Postgres** server, not the pgAdmin server

Comment: I added exceptions to my firewall and still same problem

Comment: How do you start pgAdmin?

Comment: By launching pgAdmin.exe as administrator

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any special character in your account's name?
Maybe try this? http://postgresql.nabble.com/Cannot-launch-pgAdmin4-td5924098.html#a5926072
It didn't help me, but maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: I installed older version of PostgreSql and it worked properly.

Comment: I have the same problem, however pgAdmin 3 works fine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The same problem happened to me today:

[image]

And this is how I've solved it:

**1)** Use a text editor to open the **config_distro.py** file under the **c:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v1\web** folder. Change the value for **SERVER_MODE** from *True* to *False*, then save the change. (I have run Notepad++ as an Administrator, in order to be able to save in this protected folder.)

[image]

**2)** Go to folder **c:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin** and make sure there is nothing there (delete all the files, as they are temporary and will be restored after starting **pgAdmin**)

[image]

**3)** Start **pgAdmin**

[image]

**4)** This time you will see a white box that sits - at least, on my slow laptop - about 20 seconds. (You may briefly see the original error message, but do not worry).

[image]

**5)** Meanwhile, the temporary files - required for running the application - are created.

[image]

**6)** Once the temporary files process is over, the application starts as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation (+1) from me :)

Answer (score 9):

Try starting the pgAdmin as administrator.

Answer (score 3):

My `config_distro.py` was missing this line:

```
MINIFY_HTML=False
```

I added it as in the above steps and it works

Comment: You sir, deserve a nobel

Answer (score 2):

In my case, SERVER_MODE was already False in config_distro.py. I then proceeded to start pgadmin4 as an administrator. This also did not work. Finally, I resolved this by restarting postgresql service in services.msc. 
[postgres service restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ond0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was non-ascii username.

Find pgAdmin installation and open/create `config_local.py` in editor,  add this:

```py
DATA_DIR = "C:/Data/pgAdmin" # set non-ascii path here
```

and run `setup.py` using python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the server manually - any errors will echo on the terminal. The windows app seems touchy on timing - this allows the server to take as much time as needed to start up.

Assuming you installed version 3 into "p:\pgAdmin 4" run the following commands"

```
p:
cd "\pgAdmin 4\v3\web"
set PYTHONPATH=P:\pgAdmin 4\v3\venv\Lib;P:\pgAdmin 4\v3\venv\DLLs
python pgAdmin4.py
```

When I run that I get the following output:

```
Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5050 in your browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today even though the service was running in Windows 10. I just stopped the service, gave it a few seconds, and restarted it. I was able to connect with pgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved by restarting the postgresql service.
Windows-> Service -> find for postgreSQL -> Stop and then Start